# Car starts with Trickle charger and Battary, can start on a boost but not on battary alone

Tags: battery, starting, alternator

The battary on a chevrolet cruze is displaying an output of 15 volts and recharges from the alternator. However the car needs assistance from a boost or trickle charger to turn over properly. The car when left sitting for a while will cycle over once then tick repeatedly until the battary drains further and the ticking reduces in frequency. When the car is started the car has no trouble running. no displays on the car gave come up for a fault with the battary or alternator from the dash board. I am wondering if it a question the the battary does not output enough amperage to start the vehicle anymore.

The meter used to test the voltage has been verrified to be correct in its readings and matched up voltage readings for another car that is running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not provided much information about the car or the battery, from what you described I believe this answer will still help you.

Just because a battery has full voltage and operates typical electronics, does not necessarily mean it has the amperage capacity to crank and start the engine. When you engage the starter, it puts an enormous load on the battery. This is the single most difficult task for the battery.

You should have the battery load tested. From what you have described, it is probably going/gone bad.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but based a bit more trouble shooting, If the battary is connected to a charger for 5 minutes the car starts no problem, which again leads me to believe the amperage is low or there is buildup on the internal plates of the battary. The battary's age is roughly 5 years old and has not had any issues to date, no buildup along terminals and they were cleaned and re tested. i would take the car to be tested at a canadian tire except i don't have a way of getting there until tomorrow. what is the "normal" lifespan of a battary?

Comment: @Marco that's a different question but fortunately has been answered already: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23707/what-is-the-expected-lifetime-and-failure-mode-of-lead-acid-battery

Comment: @Marco - Normal lifespan is around 5 years ... looks like it's time. If the place can test batteries, have them do a load test. My opinion is the battery has served it's useful life and is now wanting to be recycled. Give it an honorable death.

Comment: I agree that the battery is probably past its life cycle. However @Marco you can also make sure all your contact points are as clean and well-mates as possible to be sure that unnecessary resistance isn’t the problem. If the battery is failing it won’t fully solve the problem, but *could* at least get you a few more days of acceptable functioning. Either way, it’s not harmful to make sure everything in clean and tight.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time, I'll be testing everything tomorrow and give an update.

Comment: Might I also suggest careful inspection of the battery cables. If they look swollen, cracked insulation, or damaged else-wise, replace them. Corrosion increases resistance which reduces amperage available to the starter.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Changed the battery and gave it an honorable death at my local Canadian Tire. Car has no trouble starting except now the automatic start doesn't work XD. I'm off to youtube and he car manual to try and find a way to reprogram it.

Thanks again for the help everyone